# pandas apply function to multiple columns with condition and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have a df with multiple columns like this (there are many more cols & rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   {'ID': 1,'date': '2022-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,99,300]', 'vegetable_code':'[1000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'xy',}, 
                   {'ID': 2,'date': '2022-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[67,200,87]', 'vegetable_code':'[5000]','supermarket':'z, m'}, 
                   {'ID': 3,'date': '2021-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,5,300,78]', 'vegetable_code':'[7000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'wf, z'},
                   {'ID': 4,'date': '2020-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[77]', 'vegetable_code':'[1000]','supermarkt':'wf'},
                   {'ID': 5,'date': '2022-15-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,200,546,33]', 'vegetable_code':'[4000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'t, wf'},
                   {'ID': 6,'date': '2002-12-01', 'fruit_code':'[64,2]', 'vegetable_code':'[6000,8000,1000]','supermarket':'k' },
                   {'ID': 7,'date': '2018-12-01', 'fruit_code':'[5]', 'vegetable_code':'[6000,8000,1000]','supermarket':'p' }

                  ])
```

my expected df should look like this in the end:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   {'ID': 1,'date': '2022-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,99,300]', 'vegetable_code':'[1000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'xy','new_col_1':'all'}, 
                   {'ID': 2,'date': '2022-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[67,200,87]', 'vegetable_code':'[5000]','supermarket':'z, m','new_col_1':'[5000]'}, 
                   {'ID': 3,'date': '2021-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,5,300,78]', 'vegetable_code':'[7000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'wf, z','new_col_1':'all'},
                   {'ID': 4,'date': '2020-01-01', 'fruit_code':'[77]', 'vegetable_code':'[1000]','supermarket':'wf','new_col_1':'[77]'},
                   {'ID': 5,'date': '2022-15-01', 'fruit_code':'[100,200,546,33]', 'vegetable_code':'[4000,2000,3000]','supermarket':'t, wf','new_col_1':'all'},
                   {'ID': 6,'date': '2002-12-01', 'fruit_code':'[64,2]', 'vegetable_code':'[6000,8000,1000]','supermarket':'k', 'new_col_1':'[64]', 'new_col_2':'[2]'},
                   {'ID': 7,'date': '2018-12-01', 'fruit_code':'[5]', 'vegetable_code':'[6000,8000,1000]','supermarket':'p' ,'new_col_1':'all'}

                  ])
```

and here are multiple conditions I want to apply on cols fruit_code & vegetable_code to get two new columns:

**UPDATE**

```
def fruits_vegetable(row):
    if len(str(row['fruit_code'])) == 1:                                                        # fruit_code in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = row['fruit_code']
    elif len(str(row['fruit_code'])) == 1 and len(str(row['vegetable_code'])) > 1:              # write "all" in new_col_1 
        row['new_col_1'] = 'all'
    elif len(str(row['fruit_code'])) > 2 and len(str(row['vegetable_code'])) == 1:              # vegetable_code in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = row['vegetable_code']
    elif len(str(row['fruit_code'])) > 3 and len(str(row['vegetable_code'])) > 1:               # write "all" in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = 'all'
    elif len(str(row['fruit_code'])) == 2 and len(str(row['vegetable_code'])) >= 0:             # fruit 1 new_col_1 & fruit 2 new_col_2
        row['new_col_1'] = row['fruit_code'][0]
        row['new_col_2'] = row['fruit_code'][1]

    return row

df = df.apply(fruits_vegetable, axis=1)
```

I'm still stuck, now I get "all" in some of the rows for the first column, but the second does not change.

If someone has some insights, that would be great.

Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is necessary convert strings repr of lists by `ast.literal_eval` to lists, then for chceck length remove casting to strings. If need one element lists instead scalars use `[]` in `fruit[0]` and `fruit[1]` and last change order of condition for `len(fruit) == 1`, also change `len(fruit) > 3` to `len(fruit) > 2` for match first row:

```
def fruits_vegetable(row):
    
    fruit = ast.literal_eval(row['fruit_code'])
    vege = ast.literal_eval(row['vegetable_code'])
    
    if len(fruit) == 1 and len(vege) > 1:   # write "all" in new_col_1 
        row['new_col_1'] = 'all'
    elif len(fruit) > 2 and len(vege) == 1: # vegetable_code in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = vege
    elif len(fruit) > 2 and len(vege) > 1:  # write "all" in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = 'all'
    elif len(fruit) == 2 and len(vege) >= 0:# fruit 1 new_col_1 & fruit 2 new_col_2
        row['new_col_1'] = [fruit[0]]
        row['new_col_2'] = [fruit[1]]
    elif len(fruit) == 1:                   # fruit_code in new_col_1
        row['new_col_1'] = fruit
    return row


df = df.apply(fruits_vegetable, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID        date        fruit_code new_col_1 new_col_2 supermarket  \
0   1  2022-01-01      [100,99,300]       all       NaN          xy   
1   2  2022-01-01       [67,200,87]    [5000]       NaN        z, m   
2   3  2021-01-01    [100,5,300,78]       all       NaN       wf, z   
3   4  2020-01-01              [77]      [77]       NaN         NaN   
4   5  2022-15-01  [100,200,546,33]       all       NaN       t, wf   
5   6  2002-12-01            [64,2]      [64]       [2]           k   
6   7  2018-12-01               [5]       all       NaN           p   

  supermarkt    vegetable_code  
0        NaN  [1000,2000,3000]  
1        NaN            [5000]  
2        NaN  [7000,2000,3000]  
3         wf            [1000]  
4        NaN  [4000,2000,3000]  
5        NaN  [6000,8000,1000]  
6        NaN  [6000,8000,1000]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get a `ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x17c882f40>`, for `----> 6     vege = ast.literal_eval(row['vegetable_code'])`
so I guess the type is off/mixed. However, when I check if instance is str for 
vegetable_code I get True. I'm going to dig in this

Comment: Oh, did not see your edit, let me check

Comment: @iittala - maybe need change `fruit = ast.literal_eval(row['fruit_code'])` to `fruit = row['fruit_code']` if already list in real data. In sample data are lists like string, so necessary use it. Similar way use for `vege`

Comment: Did a couple of changes in my code, the real data is a mess. You helped me a lot, much appreciated!